# How would i merge 2 user ranks in one

Tags: php

Okay im stumped as im wondering how would i merge 2 user ranks into one.

1st user rank `<?php if ($user -> isAdmin($odb)) { ?>`

2nd user rank `<?php if ($user -> isStaff($odb)) { ?>`

Comment: What do you mean by one?

Comment: like i want them ranks in one line so both ranks can access link on my navigation menu. say one user is admin or another is Staff the link will appear but how would i merge both of them into one.

Comment: Hope you want this `if ($user->isAdmin($odb) || $user->isStaff($odb)) {...}`, `||` = or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "or" is actually not needed.
Your functions seems to return a boolean answer.
And boolean can be interpreted as 0 and 1 in a if.

```
if ($user -> isAdmin($odb) + $user -> isStaff($odb))
```

So by adding them together you get an answer from 0-2.
Where 0 is false, false and true, true is 2.
Since 1 and 2 is interpreted as true in PHP it will work without the or.

Try it out here: https://3v4l.org/rWf6C

Comment: While this is a witty trick there, it doesn't state clearly the intention of the author. Whoever comes a year later to make changes to the code, will rack their brains trying to understand why an arithmetic operation was used instead of a boolean one, and what was that the author intended here. I advise to write code in the most straightforward way. If you want to say OR, just say OR.

Comment: @obivan what are you talking about? I clearly say "your functions seems to return Boolean", that does explain this only works if it's bool return. And why would this be harder to understand in a year? The question will be the same, the answer will be the same. The most straight forward may not always be the best solution. But with that I'm not saying this is a better solution than "or", it's referring to other "not straight forward solutions".

Answer (score 0):

Just use `||` like this

```
if ($user -> isAdmin($odb) || $user -> isStaff($odb))
```

`||` Means OR

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<?php if ($user -> isAdmin($odb) || $user -> isStaff($odb)) { 
   //Do Something
}?>
```

|| is OR, you can use OR too